# Update form store none value when I submit the update form. How can I fix It?

Tags: django

I made a feedback form `(def feedBack)` so that a user can give feedback. It's working well. Now my motive to create an update form so that a user can be able update their feedback. I also have written a view for update feedback `(def UpdateFeedback)`. But it's not working perfectly. When I submit the update form, then it updates `none`. Where did the actual problem occur?

***views.py:***

***This view for storing feedback and it's working well.***

```
def feedBack(request,quick_view_id):
    quick_view = get_object_or_404(Products, pk=quick_view_id)
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated:

        try:
            ProductREVIEWS.objects.create(
                user=request.user,
                product=quick_view,
                feedBACK=request.POST.get('feedBACK')
            )
            return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)
        except:
            return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)

    else:
        return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)
```

---

***this view for update the feedback, but it's store*** `none`

```
def UpdateFeedback(request, id):
    feedback = ProductREVIEWS.objects.get(pk=id)
    product_id = feedback.product.id
    reviewers = feedback.user
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateFeedbackForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and reviewers.id == request.user.id:
            
            UpdateFeedbackForm(request.POST)
            feedBACK = form.cleaned_data.get('UpdateFeedBACK')
            feedback.feedBACK = feedBACK
            feedback.save()
            messages.success(request, "Feedback is updated")
    
    return redirect('quick_view', product_id)
```

***forms.py:***

```
class UpdateFeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductREVIEWS
        fields = ('feedBACK')
        
        labels = {
            'feedBACK':'Change Your View'
        }

        widgets = {
            'feedBACK':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'style':'font-size:13px;'})
        }
```

***models.py:***

```
class ProductREVIEWS(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='userREVIEW',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='productREVIEWrelatedNAME',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feedBACK = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

***urls.py:***

```
path("feedBack/<int:quick_view_id>/", views.feedBack, name="feedBack"),
path("UpdateFeedback/<int:id>/", views.UpdateFeedback, name="UpdateFeedback")
```

***template:***

```
{% for feedBack in AllProductFeedback %}
<form action="{% url 'UpdateFeedback' id=feedBack.id %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <textarea id="UpdateFeedBack" rows="6" style="font-size: 13px;" class="form-control" name="UpdateFeedBACK" value="" required>{{feedBack.feedBACK}}</textarea>

</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def UpdateFeedback(request, id):
    feedback = ProductREVIEWS.objects.get(pk=id) #  I suggest you to handle DoesNotExist exception case.

    product_id = feedback.product.id
    reviewers = feedback.user
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateFeedbackForm(request.POST, instance=feedback) #  you need to pass instance here

        if form.is_valid() and reviewers.id == request.user.id:
            
            UpdateFeedbackForm(request.POST) #  doesn't do anything here, return value ignored.
            feedBACK = form.cleaned_data.get('UpdateFeedBACK') #  Will return None, since there is no UpdateFeedBACK in form fields.
            # So you can remove two lines above.
            form.save() #  This will update the ProductREVIEWS model
            messages.success(request, "Feedback is updated")
    
        return redirect('quick_view', product_id)
```

Comment: still not working 

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: no error was shown. Form submitted but data not stored

Comment: Here is the thing, I suggest you to separate `form.is_valid()` and `reviewers.id == request.user.id` into different condition block and write else case for `form.is_valid()` where you will handle the errors (output them for example).

Comment: Also change name attribute of textarea tag to "feedBACK" which fits the model's field.

Comment: still same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246666/discussion-between-togrul-asadov-and-mossaddak).

Answer (score 0):

```
def UpdateFeedback(request, id):
    feedback = ProductREVIEWS.objects.get(pk=id)
    product_id = feedback.product.id
    reviewers = feedback.user
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateFeedbackForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and reviewers.id == request.user.id:
            
            UpdateFeedbackForm(request.POST)
            feedBACK = form.cleaned_data.get('UpdateFeedBACK') #this will not work since there is no updatefeedback field in your form
            feedback=form.save(commit=False)
            feedback.feedBACK = feedBACK #(this feedBACK need to be object of your Products model)
            feedback.save()
            messages.success(request, "Feedback is updated")
    
    return redirect('quick_view', product_id)
```

Comment: it has shown this error,,,,,,,,,,,,NOT NULL constraint failed: Ecommerce_app_productreviews.product_id

Comment: show your Products model

Comment: class Products(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="merchandise_product_related_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length = 250)
    product_desc = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    product_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    product_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="categoty_related_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

Comment: as i mention in the answer feedback.feedBACK=feedBACK (object.field=object) #This feedBACK after equal sign is the object of your Products class so create object and assign like this your apps must work fine!

Comment: I didn't get your point. How will I create the object, where have to assign it. Please writr for me

Comment: I have made an object,, but how will i WRITE HERE( feedback.feedBACK=feedBACK (object.field=object))

Comment: ProductObject = Products()(This an object)

Comment: object.field this object is created from ProductReviews model and which is ultimately productReviewsForm and the field name is feedBACK thats why we write feedback.feedBACK now after the equal sign you have to pass the object of your Products model that's how we linked model if we created relation using foreignkey